# MVC3 action that do not refresh session expiration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have one ajax request that refresh some counter in our layout page. The ajax request is made all 2 minutes.

but with this request the session never expire unless the user logout or close the browser.
How can I make an action that do not refresh the session expiration ?

Comment: you do **NOT** want the session to expire?

Comment: I do want the session to expire if the user left. The ajax request slide the expiration and I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: I believe that you would need to turn slidingExpiration off in the web.config and handle increasing the session expiration time manually in other sections of your code (ActionFilter or something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm under the impression that if you don't use the Session (read/write) it won't slide. But you can apply the SessionState attribute to your controller to disable it to that controller (it won't work at action level though).

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
}
```